# Manifolds as homology classes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I have found that a k-dimensional submanifold of a manifold M can be considered as a class in the homology group $H_{k}(M)$.
Why ?

Comment: What do you mean "you have found"? Did you read that somewhere? And are you sure it's not a class in $H_k(M)$?

Comment: Sorry, it is $H_{k}(M)$, I have read that in the book principles of algebraic geometry,  Griffiths and Harris.

Comment: OK, my answer is for when there are orientation assumptions. Is it the case in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X \subset M$ is an *oriented* submanifold of $M$, then $X$ has a top homology class $[X] \in H_k(X)$. It gets sent, via the inclusion $i : X \to M$, to a class $i([X]) \in H_k(M)$. This is generally what is meant by considering a submanifold as a homology class; I'm not sure it makes sense for nonoriented manifolds.

Comment: You also need to assume that $X$ is compact, if you want a fundamental class.

Comment: Yes, $X$ must in fact be closed (compact, without boundary).